# how is the subclass property "quantity" initialised

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, subclass, superclass

I'm trying to learn the concept of inheritance and initialisation in swift and have came up with the following code. "the swift programming language 2.1" states that if a subclass provides implementation of all of its superclass's designated initialiser, the subclass also automatically inherits all of its superclass convenience initialisers too.

Therefore the subclass "`RecipeIngredient`" should have inherited superclass "`Food`"'s `convenience init(){ self.init(name: "[unnamed]")`. But this particular convenience init only initialise the var `name`, how can it initialise the subclass property `quantity`? Could someone please explain it to me, how is the subclass property `quantity` initialised when I create an instance of subclass using the superclass `convenience init(){ self.init(name: "[unnamed]")`? Thanks in advance for any help!

```
class Food {
    var name: String
    init(name: String){
        self.name = name
    }
    convenience init() {
        self.init(name: "[unnamed]")
    }

}




class RecipeIngredient: Food{
    var quantity: Int
    init(name: String, quantity: Int){
        self.quantity = quantity
        super.init(name: name)
    }

    override convenience init(name: String){
        self.init(name: name, quantity: 1)
    }
}


let ingredientOne = RecipeIngredient()
ingredientOne.name
ingredientOne.quantity
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute

```
let ingredientOne = RecipeIngredient()
```

the method `Food.init()` runs, and calls `self.init(name:String)`. `self` is actually an instance of `RecipeIngredient`, so this method is actually `RecipeIngredient.init(name:String)` which you have provided to initialise the `quantity`.

It's possible to confirm this by putting a `print` statement at each of the `init` routines to see which methods are called in which order.

If I comment out the method `RecipeIngredient.init(name:String)` the compiler will no longer let me write `RecipeIngredient()`.